# How to resolve this...please let me know

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p4Zu.png)ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds." ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."

Please Resolve This Problem

Comment: I think you are using beta software

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.". That's pretty explicit, no ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory - don't use OS X or Xcode betas for apps you are going to submit, use current versions (from the App Store, for example).

Comment: Is it downloaded from app store?