# ERROR ITMS-90207 Apple Store Submisson

Tags: ios, xcode, publishing

My app works perfectly when I'm running it on the simulator or device (for debug and release build configuration). But when I try to submit my app to the Apple Store I got the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'APPNAME.app' does
>   not contain a bundle executable."

I tried to upload the archive with Xcode and Application Loader, without success.

[image]

I have tried some of the solutions found in this topic ([Xcode App Submisson ERROR ITMS-90207: "Invalid Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369777/xcode-app-submisson-error-itms-90207-invalid-bundle)) but none of them work with my project:

- CFBundleExecutable is declared in my plist file as $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
- I tried to disable Bitcode
- I tried to remove all CFBundleExecutable form Pods plist files (keep only the one from my target's plist)

Maybe this error is related to Xcode version... My mac is running macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6 Beta (16G8c), Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) and Application Loader Version 3.0 (620).

Any help is welcome.

**UDPATE:**

I try with Xcode 8.2, I have the same error.

Here is my plist file for more detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>APPNAME</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb000000</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>639</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>000000</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>APPNAME</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Description...</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Description...</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Description...</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**UDPATE 2:**

I managed to publish the archive from another mac with Xcode 8.2.1.
I try with Xcode version 8.2 an 8.2.1 on my mac, but I still have the same error.
I have also tried Application Loader version 3.0 and 3.6, without success...
So it looks like, the problem comes from my mac. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Are you using any third party items?

Comment: Yes I use Cocoapods to install some thrid party libraries: Firebase, Onesignal, SDWebImage, ... do you think the error comes from one of them?

Comment: It may. I've seen similar questions here over the last 7 months. Since I do not use third party apps I can't be of help, but try searching here on that kind of thing. Cocoapods need some things beyond a straight first party submission, I think. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: I have already used third party libraries with cocoapods with other apps, and I haven't experienced any problem to publish them to the Apple Store. Thanks for your help

Comment: try setting `LSRequiresIPhoneOS` to `YES` if it's not there in `info.plist`

Comment: I already have this setting in my plist file (I've updated my question with the plist file for more detail). Thank you

Comment: You are doing your work in a workspace and not the project file, right? .xcworkspace vs .xcproject I believe

Comment: I open the project form the xcworkspace file.

Comment: I managed to publish the archive from another mac with Xcode 8.2.1. Not sure if it's the Mac, Xcode or Application Loader. I'm downloading Xcode 8.2.1 on my mac to make it sure. I'll tell you about it tonight.

Comment: @Bogy: Avoid publishing with XCode betas and/or OSX betas.

Comment: @Larme: I think you are right. I am going to wait a stable version to try again...

Comment: @Bogy In your case, you might have fallen into that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025979/how-to-resolve-this-please-let-me-know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have contacted the Apple Developer Technical Support, and as @Larme suggest in the comments above, the error is due to my beta version of macOS.

Here is the full Apple support answer:

> I looked at the .ipa you provided that was giving trouble, and
>   compared it to the one successfully submitted to the App Store. The
>   one giving you trouble was built on a beta version of macOS, which is
>   not supported for distribution. Apps released to the App Store need to
>   be built for a GM version of macOS, with a GM version of Xcode, using
>   a GM version of the iOS SDK.
>
> Normally, apps submitted with any beta software receive a message
>   indicating this problem, and the message you received
>   was completely misleading.

I am going to complete the Bug Reporter form to report this bug.
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ridiculously enough, you also get this error if you try to submit a 9.0 deployment target app with XCode 9.1. Switchting the deployment target to 11.1 "fixed" it.

My hunch is that it is related to this:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

"Deprecations: Apps with a deployment target of iOS 11 no longer build a 32-bit slice. To build and include a 32-bit slice, set the deployment target to an earlier version of iOS. (32163517)"