# Can publish app to iTunes connect with Mac OS Mojave?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, beta

I wanted to know if it is possible to install the MacOS Mojave beta and then use Xcode to publish a project on iTunes connect. I remember that in the past beta this was not possible.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't satisfied with the previous answer (specially concerning the beta macOS component) ... and I really wanted to install Mojave, so I went hunting for some docs or verification. The closest I got is this quoted answer from Apple Developer Technical Support related to a failed submission with an odd ITMS error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323416/322147

> I looked at the .ipa you provided that was giving trouble, and
>   compared it to the one successfully submitted to the App Store. The
>   one giving you trouble was built on a beta version of macOS, which is
>   not supported for distribution. Apps released to the App Store need to
>   be built for a GM version of macOS, with a GM version of Xcode, using
>   a GM version of the iOS SDK.
>
> Normally, apps submitted with any beta software receive a message
>   indicating this problem, and the message you received was completely
>   misleading.

Comment: I've successfully uploaded an iOS app to the App Store for TestFlight distribution using Xcode 9 and Mojave.

Comment: It should be noted that you can upload apps for TestFlight testing using beta software but those will not be accepted if you try and submit those for approval to be sold in the store.

Comment: I think you can use a virtual machine like Parallels with stable Xcode and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not submit a build of your app that was built with either Xcode 10 or macOS Mojave at this time. Apple does not allow apps built with any beta software to be published.